# What is the significance of the index number in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is how I create indexes in in my Mongo DB with mongoose:

```
UserSchema.index({
 email: 1,
 username: 1
}, {unique: true});
```

I initially just had email, but bc username is unique as well and because I'm checking if a username exists when a user creates a username I want to index username as well. What does the "1" next to it mean? Should I make the username "2" instead of "1"? I am new to indexes and just want to make sure that those 2 fields are indexed individually.

Comment: Hi dev189, please consider accepting my answer if it was correct and of use.

Answer (score 3):

An index of 1 means the collection of records named "email" and the collections of records named "username" will be sorted in ascending order, whereas putting a -1 means they will be sorted in reverse order.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-results-single-field